# String refs in C#

Tags: c#, string, reference

I have two arrays:

```
 string[] arr1 = {"foo","bar","bazz"};
 string[] arr2 = arr1;

 public void changeArr(ref string[] a){
     a[0] = "moo";
 }

 changeArr(ref arr2);
```

It is working as it should but in case of strings I try to do the same

```
 string str1 = "foo";
 string str2 = str1;

 public static void changeStr(ref string a){
     a = "bar";
 }

 changeStr(ref str2);
```

But it changes only str2, as I know strings are ref types so str1 and str2 should point to the same address in memory and also changeStr() should change str1 as well.

I tried to remove ref as it is already ref type but it did not changed even str2. I also tried to pass ref str1 to str2 but it gave error.

Comment: In the first example, the variables are referring to an array which contains strings. This is similar to variables referring to an object, you can change the fields using either variable, and change the array using either variable. The second two variables point to a string, if you change one to point to a different string, that doesn't change the other.

Comment: The difference is that in the first case you are not actually modifying `arr1` or `arr2` inside the function ; it'd work the same without `ref` being used. You're modifying something "inside" the object those names are associated with.

Answer (score 2):

It is true strings are reference types. It is also true there is some extra work done for C# to give strings at least the appearance of value-semantics for certain things. For example, you can create a string object with a literal, rather than calling a constructor via the `new` keyword. However, it's important to understand this only comes into play in a small way.

Rather, the trick in this situation is understanding the difference between a variable and a reference. `str1` and `str2` both initially refer to the same `"foo"` string object, but they are still different variables and not otherwise connected. If you assign a new object to one or the other, the remaining variable still refers to the original `"foo"` object.

In this case, when assigning the string `"bar"` to `a`, you are assigning *an entirely new string object* to the `a` variable, and this includes the `str2` variable thanks to the `ref` keyword. (This is where the value semantics matter; without understanding this it's less obvious `"bar"` creates and assigns a whole new object.) But the main thing is `str1` still points to the old `"foo"` object.

> str1 and str2 should point to the same address in memory and also changeStr() should change str1

The reason this is incorrect is `changeStr()` effectively changed where `str2` points to, but there is no reason for this to also modify `str1`. They used to point to the same address, and now they don't, because they are not the same variable.

---

Similarly, consider the array sample without the `ref` keyword at all:

```
string[] arr1 = {"foo","bar","bazz"};
string[] arr2 = arr1;

public void changeArr(string[] a){
    a[0] = "moo";
}

changeArr(arr2);
```

When this code runs `arr1[0]` will also change to `"moo"` instead of `"foo"`, *even without the `ref` keyword.* This is because `arr1` and `arr2` are set to the same array object, and arrays are reference types. Therefore when calling the `chargeArr()` method we still passed the method a reference to the array, rather than copying the whole array. It's a copy of the reference, but it's still a reference. We only have one array object in the entire code sample, and we only changed one element in the array: not the array itself. Even though we changed an element within the array, it's still the same object referred to by `arr1`.

---

However, if you were to do this then `arr1` would remain unchanged, just like with the strings:

```
string[] arr1 = {"foo","bar","bazz"};
string[] arr2 = arr1;

public void changeArr(ref string[] a){
    a = {"moo","bar","bazz"};
}

changeArr(ref arr2);
```

This is because now we replaced the entire object, and now the `ref` keyword was needed for the object assignment to be visible outside the method.

---

So we see passing reference types by `ref` in C# connects the variables themselves. Most of the time in C# using the `ref` keyword in this way is a mistake. You should prefer program designs that don't need it.

---

In summary, in C#:

- Both arrays and strings are reference types
- Passing reference types to a method normally (no `ref`) copies the reference, but still passes a reference rather than the object. The method has a *new variable* that refers the *same object*.
- Passing reference types to a method with the `ref` keyword gives you the "original" reference, which is equivalent to passing the variable itself.
- If you have multiple variables referring to the same object, and you act on a property, method, or field of that object, any change is visible on all variables for that object (you acted on the object, not the variables).
- If you have multiple variables referring to the same object, and you use assignment to make one to refer to a completely different object, other variables are unchanged (assignments are operations on variables, rather than operations on objects).

Comment: Also important to notice, the first example changes one "slot" inside the array, and not the whole reference, that might also add to Op's confusion. That would mean he tries to replace one char inside the string if he tested equivalently.
*edit* nice that you made the difference clear.